# Indenting schema, is there a sort of thing you can load/configure into "=" in vim?

Tags: indentation

I don't know what vim cannot do, so far, I feel it is so powerful!

I need indent in Normal Mode for c++ code. I found vim is using "***=***" to that, just visual/mouse select the code and hit "=" key, or doing "gg=G" for all.

The following style is what I need (no indentation after a keyword). It might be ugly, but let's just don't discuss that. I'm using it as an example.

```
template< class T > class Stack
{
    public:
    Stack(int = default_value);
    Stack()//destructor
    {delete [] values;}
    bool push( T );
    T pop();
    bool isEmpty();
    bool isFull();
    private:
    int size;
    T *values;
    int index;
};
```

After "=" indenting, I got the following code

```
template< class T > class Stack
{
    public:
        Stack(int = default_value);
        Stack()//destructor
        {delete [] values;}
        bool push( T );
        T pop();
        bool isEmpty();
        bool isFull();
    private:
        int size;
        T *values;
        int index;

};
```

**Question:** Is there a way to configure/change the indentation style/schema behind the "=" operator or Is there a mechanism to load some sort of indentation schema into the "=" in vim?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your specific query (indentation of statements following a C++ scope declaration), you can use Vim's C-indenting and add the `h` setting to `cinoptions`:

```
" Use C-indenting
:set cindent

" Don't indent further after scope declaration
:set cinoptions+=h0
```

More generally, you can also use either an external program or Vimscript to configure the behaviour of the `=` command.

Use the `'equalprg'` option to specify an external program or the `'indentexpr'` option to specify a (Vimscript) indent expression.

For more details, see:

- `:help C-indenting`
- `:help cinoptions`
- `:help cino-h`
- `:help =`
- `:help 'equalprg'`
- `:help 'indentexpr'`
- `:help indent-expression`